# Generate Google Endpoints library (JDO) with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, jdo, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to generate an JDO based endpoint from Android Studio, but the library is not being generated (and no error is shown). The only warning I can see is the one below regarding the annotations.

This is my gradle log:

```
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:head:appengineDownloadSdk
:head:compileJava
warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning

:head:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:head:classes
:head:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs
API client library written to C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Komi\head\build\client-libs\registration-v1-java.zip
API client library written to C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Komi\head\build\client-libs\messaging-v1-java.zip
:head:appengineEndpointsExpandClientLibs
```

The two showed API client library are the ones based in objectify and but the third one (JDO based) is missing and seems to be being skipped.I would appreciate some help, thank you!

This is the gradle file (not different from docs):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.9'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.9'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.9'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.9'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
  compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
  compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'
  compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.4'
  compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the error about enhancing? I see none.

Comment: Well, maybe there is not an error there, I thought it would be enhancer related as long as the only info I can see is a warning about annotations and the endpoint library generation is being skipped for the JDO one. 
Thanks about pointing that, I am editing the question to remove the enhancing-error reference.

Comment: can you take a look at your web.xml to see if you've added your endpoints in there?  That's where the endpoints are parsed from.

Also you're definitely going to need to enhance JDO classes. Use the appengine->enahncer closure for this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

Comment: It was that, thanks @loosebazooka . Now I having issues enhancing my classes. I have follow another answer from you by adding 
enhancer {
   enhanceOnBuild=true
   api="jdo"
   version="v2"}

but exception "org.datanucleous already registered" keep raising. Weird thing is that Android Studio marks this enhancer definition and gives me a "Cannot resolve symbol enhancer" , so maybe it is not using the correct version of the appengine-plugin.

Comment: You might need to include some more information about why the exception is happening.  Try running appengineEnhance from the command line with the --info flag to print the location of the log file. The log file should have more details. You might be including a dependency that you don't need to because the enhancer already includes it for you (or perhaps you're including the wrong version?)

Comment: @loosebazooka I checked again dependencies discovering that I was getting diferent versions for datanucleous-core and datanucleous-api-jdo (3.1.4 and 3.1.3), changing to get both 3.1.3 fixed the issue and now enhancer is working fine. 

Thanks you so much for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a couple of things in order to make it work (thanks to @loosebazooka)

1) First add the endpoints to the web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.something.else.Userendpoint, com.something.else.AnotherEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

2) I had an error in my dependencies (different versions for datanucleous-core and datanucleous-jdo-api. As soon as I changed the dependencies to both 3.1.3 version enhancing started to work fine and Google endpoints became awesome again.